# Is there any Html5 Application cache loader tool?

Tags: html, caching, web

Is there any tool that can load an application cache to the browser cache once you have the application cache in hand?

say my app cache manifest (say example.appcache) contains the following content

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1.0

CACHE:
1.html
2.html
3.html
```

and i have the cache files in hand will i be able to deploy the content to the browser cache? ( in chrome browser )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do? It sounds like you need the swapCache function. [A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant section from the article referenced by Craig Shoemaker is this:

> To programmatically update the cache, first call applicationCache.update(). This will attempt to update the user's cache (which requires the manifest file to have changed). Finally, when the applicationCache.status is in its UPDATEREADY state, calling applicationCache.swapCache() will swap the old cache for the new one.